# How can I use grunt-sync to sync a single file (specifically web.config)?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm attempting to have the web.config of the site update only if changed.  As configured below, this erases the entire contents of the website except for web.config.  Any ideas on how to configure this?  "siteFolder" is defined elsewhere.

```
        webconfig: {
            files: [
                { src: ['web.config'], dest: siteFolder }
            ],
            ignoreInDest: ['!web.config'],
            pretend: true,
            updateAndDelete: true,
            compareUsing: "md5",
            verbose: true
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

by doing:

```
updateAndDelete: false
```

It will only update those files.  It won't handle deletes, but thats OK in this case.